# Send messages from firefox after loggedin

Tags: javascript, firefox, authentication, firefox-addon, kerberos

I am working on an addon and I also have a website to which users login. Website authentication is based on Kerberos (protocol). Once the user logs into the website I want to send messages on behalf of user from addon. How do I send messages to the webserver on user's behalf.  Where are te authentication details saved for Kerberos authentication? DO I need to create headers myself for my messages to be accepted by the webserver?

I am planning to send the message from addon using javascript/jquery

Answer (score 0):

Use an xmlhttprequest that uses cookies.
This one does the trick:
https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9088113

example usage of it:
https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9096743

this example here wont work for you because it makes execution WITHOUT the cookie I THINK
https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/11207278